# Nodemon installed but not working in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, npm, node-modules

I am using `Node.js` with `express.js` and I also installed Nodemon ( exist in node_modules folder) but it's not working.
Here is my `package.json` code. How can I solve this ?

```
// package.json

{
    "name": "node-api",
    "main": "server.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "~4.0.0",
        "mongoose": "~3.6.13",
        "body-parser": "~1.0.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add nodemon as a dev dependency

```
npm i -D nodemon
```

Or install globally

```
npm i -g nodemon
```

But , in second method it will not show in package.json file

There is no need to use --save or -S as it is not used in your main code

EDIT: Jan 6, 2019
Use nodemon in script tag in `package.json` file. Like

```
"scripts" : {
...
"start" : "nodemon index.js"
}
```

Then use `npm start` in terminal

Answer (score 0):

hit `npm install --save nodemon -g` in terminal or 
install in your project via `npm install --save nodemon` 
and it should display your package.json like

```
{
    "name": "node-api",
    "main": "server.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "~4.0.0",
        "mongoose": "~3.6.13",
        "body-parser": "~1.0.1",
        "nodemon": "^1.18.6"
       }
}
```

and run `nodemon server.js`

check if nodemon is installed `nodemon -v`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is very much common. It showed 'found 0 vulnerabilities' while installing but never showed in dev dependencies.

I tried restarting my text editor and run the command again

```
npm i --save-dev nodemon
```

it started working.

Answer (score -2):

In my case i able to solve this issue by update the node.
now for  update you have to download node from https://nodejs.org/en/

it worked for me 
hope will work for you as well